# Does an HTML element have a prototype (like Element.prototype.myFunc)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make animations, and I want to be able to do this:

```
document.getElementById("item").move()
```

instead of this:

```
move(document.getElementById("item"))
```

I tried achieving that with Object.prototype.move, but that didn't work.

Comment: What have you try so far ? Please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM `HTMLElement` is an `Object` so it should work, however, an `Object` is not necessarily an `HTMLElement`, so you should add that method to `HTMLElement.prototype` instead:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.move = function() {
  let position = 0;
  const self = this;

  function render() {
    self.style = `left: ${position++}px`;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

document.getElementById('square').move();
```

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
</div>
```